# std::map, custom comparator's design constraints

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator

I have been trying defining a custom comparator for std::map container.

The question is : can I relay on == and != operators or would that break strict weak order ? Am I forced to use operator < ?

(One and Two classes do have operator!= and operator== defined correctly)

```
typedef std::pair<One, Two> MapKey_t;
class cmp
{
    bool operator()(const MapKey_t& left, const MapKey_t& right) const
    { return left.first != right.first && right.first == right.second; }
}

typedef std::map<MapKey_t, Three*, cmp> MyMap_t;
```

Since switching left with right would not change the comparator return value, will this be working?

I don't really care about how the items are sorted into the container, but I do not want duplicates to be part of it.

**Update** :

can I use the memory address to obtain strict weak ordering ?

```
class cmp
{
    bool operator()(const MapKey_t& left, const MapKey_t& right) const
    { 
        if(left.first == right.first)
            if(left.second != right.second)
                return false; // This represents for me, functionally, a duplicate
            else
                // Can't use operator < there since left.second equals right.second but
                // functionally for me, this is not a duplicate and should be stored
                // what about memory address strict weak ordering ?
                return &left < &right;
        else
            return left.first < right.first; // There I can use operator <
}
```

Comment: "Am I forced to use operator < ?" -- no, but you are forced to implement a comparator that behaves like an ordering (specifically a strict weak order).

Comment: Can I use the memory address to have strict weak ordering ?

Comment: Not in this case, because when the map inserts a new entry it might (I think most likely would) use the address of the `MapKey_t` passed to it as a parameter. Once the entry is in the map it would use the address of the `MapKey_t` stored in the container, which is a copy of same value in a different location. If the comparator is inconsistent over time then you get UB, so it should depend only on the value of the `MapKey_t`, not on its address.

Comment: Why would the comparator be inconsistent over time if the address doesn't change ?

Comment: The lifetime of this map is very short and I don't serialize the values therefore I can't see why I cant rely on addresses, assuming they won't change, the adress would ensure A < B != B < A .
I have updated the post, could you check my new comparator sample code ?

Comment: The lifetime of the map is irrelevant. It also doesn't matter whether you care about the order of the elements in the map, the map cares. If your comparator is not a strict weak order then it fails, and using the address will fail because of inconsistency when the key is copied from the parameter to the map element. The first branch is also wrong. You cannot return `true` for duplicate entries, you must return `false`, because it's a *strict* order. If you don't understand what a strict weak order is then you must look it up.

Comment: OK for the `false` that was an oversight, but with such change, could it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rely on self consistent equals or not equals because these do not establish a strict weak ordering. The comparator return value **should** change if you switch the left and right arguments. It is essential for the map to be able to establish an ordering of elements, not just be able to distinguish whether two elements are equal.

It is very important that, is `A < B` is true, then `B < A` is false. Furthermore, if `A < B` and `B < C` are both true, then `A < C` is also true.

If you do not want to or cannot establish a strict weak ordering for your types, then, then you could use a map that doesn't require it: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)<sup>1</sup>, which is a hash map. However, this will require that you provide a hashing function and an equality comparison. It also requires that your compiler have C++11 support.

<sup>1</sup> *As @JohnDibling points out in comments, `std::unordered_map` is unfortunately named. It should have been `std::hash_map` but apparently that name could have clashed with `hash_maps` from other libraries. In any case, the intent is not to have a map that is not ordered, but to have one with constant time look-up.*

Comment: `unordered_map` is unfortunately named.  It's purpose in life is not simply to provide an associative container in which there is no ordering.  Its purpose is to provide a Standard implementation of a hash map.  I'm not sure I'd suggest using an `unordered_map` just to get around the need to implement strict weak ordering.  It solves a different problem.

Answer (score 5):

You may not care how things are ordered in the map, but the map does.  The code you've provided above does not appear to implement strict weak ordering correctly.  As you have already noted that switching left with right will not change the result of `operator()` in all cases, your function does not implement strict weak ordering.

You do not necesarrily have to implement the comparator in terms of `operator<` directly, but you must ensure that if `operator()(A,B)` returns `true`, then `operator()(B,A)` does not also return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is unacceptable, string weak ordering means that `A < B` and `B < A` shall not be true at the same time. `std::map` relies on this to establish both ordering and equality of the keys